# What does it mean when Twitter says their entire database is in RAM?

Tags: sql, optimization, nosql

I am wondering where to begin with database scaling/optimization strategies.  After reading articles like [highscalability.com's facebook architecture article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/10/26/facebooks-memcached-multiget-hole-more-machines-more-capacit.html), and [this twitter architecture article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/Twitter-Architecture), I am not sure if by RAM they mean *only* memcached, or something else.

My questions are:

- Can entire SQL databases be stored in RAM?  I'm thinking sharding and all that here...  Just learning (not from a db background).
- Are SQL database indexes stored in RAM?
- Are NOSQL databases stored in RAM?  Can they be?
- Or is Memcached the standard for storing things in RAM?  So 99% of requests read from RAM (Memcached), and the database (disk) is a backup?

Just looking for a point in the right direction.